# Semi transparent layer in between content and background image - CSS

Tags: html, css

I am trying to add a semi transparent layer in between the background image and content.But any how layer is not showing.I used z-index but not working.Is there any solution here for this?Or i need to make absolute positioned both background image and background color?

If i use z-index : -1 it goes behind all..and if i use 1 the i comes front of all

```
<div class="bg">
  <div class="mask"></div>
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Hello There</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

And Css Codes are

```
.bg{
  background: url('http://support.kaziwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/member-1.png') no-repeat;
  height:200px;

}
.content{padding:70px 130px}
.mask{
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  opacity:0.3;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2kcx1L2n/

Comment: One note: attribute `content:'';` used with `:before` and `:after` pseudo-selectors only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can simply use a `linear-gradient` as a second background over the image:

```css
.bg {
  background: 
  linear-gradient(rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3)),
  url('http://support.kaziwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/member-1.png') center/cover no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
}

.content {
  padding: 70px 130px
}
```

```html
<div class="bg">
  <div class="content">
    <h2>Hello There</h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `position:relative` to the parent `div` and the content `div`. Try this CSS code.

```
.bg {
  background: url('http://support.kaziwood.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/06/member-1.png') no-repeat;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
}

.content {
  padding: 70px 130px;
  position: relative;
}

.mask {
  background: #000;
  position: absolute;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  opacity: 0.3;
  z-index: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved with fewer elements and a simplified structure using pseudo content.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2kcx1L2n/1/).

```
<div>
  <h2>Hello, there</h2>
</div>
```

Then the CSS:

```
/* main container */
div {
  background: url('my-pic.png') center/cover;
  height:200px;
  width: 400px;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center; 
  padding-top: 3em;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

/* pseudo content for overlay */
div::before{
  content:'';
  background:#000;
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  left:0;
  top:0;
  opacity:.3;
}

/* content - make sure it sits above overlay */
div > * { position: relative; z-index: 1; }
div h2 { color: white; }
```